# why do you have to execute sqllite statements asynchronously on iOS to get results?

Tags: ios, sql, sqlite, core-data, asynchronous

I'm using the [remail](http://code.google.com/p/remail-iphone/) project code, and I was trying to search the sqllite database to match subjects with the sender and receiver fields in order to establish email threading (I know.. jwz [advised](http://www.jwz.org/doc/threading.html) against using dbases for email threading it but that's a different story).

I noticed that whenever I do this synchronously.. my sqlite3_step() statement returns nothing (if i run the exact same sql query on SqlliteManager for example that has the same code.. i get the results i'm looking for)..

I then noticed that remail does all their database work asynchronously (see [here](https://github.com/abbood/remailPOP3/blob/master/remail-iphone/Classes/SearchRunner.m) for a examples from their code).. so I tried running my same query using their asynchronous way and sure enough I got the results I wanted from sqlite3_step().

**Question:** is there a reason why sqllite interaction on iOS has to be asynchronous? (notice that i'm **not** using Core Data.. the remail folks [hacked and used](https://github.com/abbood/remailPOP3/tree/master/remail-iphone/sqlite3) sqllite directly.

Comment: SQLite works fine in many synchronous programs. I'd guess there is something wrong with your code (which you didn't show).